Neural Network erros in NetEncoders?
I'm making a fairly complex neural network, and I've listed all the ports, the network flow, and the layers well. However, when I tried to run the NetGraph, it gave me the error message
NetGraph::invedgesrc: {NetPort[p1a_hpp],NetPort[p1b_hpp]} is not a valid source for p1FieldHPP. Looking into the stacktrace, the errors seem to actually be in the NetEncoders though.
When I first open the stacktrace, I see this:

Then, there aren't any errors for a while, but about halfway down the trace, everything becomes red. All of these things are the labels for the encoders though, which, in small-scale layer tests, proved no issue.

I'm genuinely unclear on what I could've messed up on. Can anyone offer any insight as to why the encoders could be acting this way?
Update: I tweaked a few things and now the error message says NetGraph::netinvgport: p1f_hpp is neither a valid input or output port for the given NetGraph. However, "pf1_hpp" here is defined in both the NetPorts and inside the InputPorts for one of the layers.

I feel like these issues are all stemming from the same core principle, but I'm unsure what it is.
